# Additional data: URL key for specified store already exists even after deleting catalog_product_entity

Tags: magento2

I keep getting

Additional data: URL key for specified store already exists.

when i try to import the csv products even after deleting the catalog_product_entity table completely.

Is there any other table to be deleted.

I see the product ids gets incremented even after truncating the table.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably check the url_rewrites table as well. It will still have the request path from the original import.